# facebook like comments error in php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, facebook

i am using facebooking connection script following

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
//<![CDATA[
document.write("<fb:like-box href='http://www.facebook.com/pages/mailData /172363602798423' width='692' show_faces='true' stream='true' header='true'></fb:like-box>");
//]]>   
</script>
```

from last three months it working fine but now it give me the following reponse and the comments section completly black

```
for (;;);{"__ar":1,"payload":null,"domops":[["replace","#stream_loading_indicator",false,{"__html":"\u003Cul class=\"uiList uiStream translateParent\" id=\"ulvg59_1\">\u003C\/ul>"}]],"css":["zz0nI"],"onload":["DOM.scry($(\"ulvg59_1\"), \"a\").forEach(function(a) {  a.target=\"_blank\";  if (a.rel == \"theater\") {    a.rel = \"\";    a.ajaxify = \"\";  }})"],"resource_map":{"zz0nI":{"type":"css","permanent":1,"src":"http:\/\/static.ak.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v1\/y0\/r\/w7wDxOViCoW.css"}}}
```

Comment: Why are you `document.write`ing that? Doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

From the Facebook docs (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/):

> FBML has been deprecated. Starting June 1, 2012 FBML apps will no
>   longer work as all FBML endpoints will be removed. If you are building
>   a new application on Facebook.com, please implement your application
>   using HTML, JavaScript and CSS. You can use our JavaScript SDK and
>   Social Plugins to embedded many of the same social features available
>   in FBML.

Instruction for setting up a like box with the current API can be found at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

Comment: i am using the old version, and i am not creating the new application but actually handling the above error